# Wrapping one of two stacked FlexLayouts

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a horizontal StackLayout that contains two FlexLayouts. The StackLayout is aligned at the top right of the screen. Now I would like the left FlexLayout (here called LeftStack, see code below) to be able to grow horizontally and once there are too many items for a single row; to wrap to a new line. I tried two things

1. Setting the Wrap property to Wrap but the left FlexLayout then wraps each item immediately instead of expanding the FlexLayout horizontally and I get a column of items :(
2. Setting Direction to RowReverse which results in all items of the left FlexLayout to vanish. Well, that is unexpected :(

How do you get the left FlexLayout to wrap once there are too may items for a single row? The first wrapped item should show up underneath the dark green BoxView. The screenshot shows what I would like to achieve (and not the result of the posted code). Any ideas how to make the left FlexLayout wrap?

[image: screenshot])

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="Start">
        <StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="End"
            Margin="0,50,0,0"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            BackgroundColor="White">
            
            <FlexLayout x:Name="LeftStack" 
                        Direction="Row"
                        Wrap="Wrap">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkRed" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkGray" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
            </FlexLayout>

            <FlexLayout x:Name="RightStack"
                        Direction="Row">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightCoral" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGreen" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="60" FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
        </FlexLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi ,sorry for not too much understanding what your wants , could you share another image to explain the needed effect ?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I changed my question so it get clearer what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

If set `WidthRequest` of **LeftStack**  , then will be able to grow horizontally . And need to remove `FlexLayout.Grow` of each `BoxView`.

```
...
<FlexLayout x:Name="LeftStack"
            JustifyContent="End"
            WidthRequest="300"
            Wrap="Wrap">
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkRed"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkGreen"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkKhaki"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkCyan"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60"/>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="60" />
</FlexLayout>
...
```

The effect :

[image]

**Note** : If need to make grow direction from right to left , need to set `JustifyContent="End"` .Otherwise , default is from left to right .

===================================Update================================

Also can use **FlexLayout** as root layout , then will no need to set width .

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="End" BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite">

    <FlexLayout x:Name="LeftStack"
                FlexLayout.Grow="3"
                JustifyContent="End"
                Wrap="Wrap">
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkRed"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkGray"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkGreen"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkKhaki"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Firebrick"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkCyan"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60"/>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="DarkSlateGray"
                    WidthRequest="100"
                    HeightRequest="60" />

</FlexLayout>

    <FlexLayout x:Name="RightStack" FlexLayout.Grow="1" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                Direction="Row">
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightCoral"
                    WidthRequest="60"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1" />
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                    WidthRequest="60"
                    HeightRequest="60"
                    FlexLayout.Grow="1" />
    </FlexLayout>
</FlexLayout>
```

Now the effect :

[image]

Comment: Changing the Direction to Column does not solve the problem unfortunately. What I want is that the red boxview wraps to a new line since there is not enough space in a single row for it. After wrapping it should sit underneath the dark blue box

Comment: @MouseOnMars Okey , if set `WidthRequest` for `LeftStack` will achieve that , I will update answer .

Comment: is there a way to do this without the width request? Ideally the solution should work for any type of device and so I cannot specify a hard-coded width.

Comment: @MouseOnMars Here need to set width request because the root layout is `StackLayout`  . Therefore , the element of flexlayout can not grow automatically .

Comment: @MouseOnMars If using  `FlexLayout` as root layout will not need to set width request , have a look at my updated answer .

Comment: It is true that the left flyout wraps now. However, the width ratios of the two flexlayouts are hard-coded by using the grow properties. If I add items to the right flexlayout then its items get compressed. I start to believer there is no good way doing this with nested flexlayout. Maybe I need to put all items in one FlexLayout then the wrapping should work no matter what

Comment: @MouseOnMars Yeah ,that will need a hard-coded `Grow` property . There are two flexlayouts here , the `Grow` property is needed . Because not knowing the scene of your project , this would be a good workaround . If answer be helpful , remember to mark that or vote it up when you have time.